# web3.eth.compile.solidity enable/disable optimization

Tags: solidity, web3js, compiler

Is there any way to enable/disable compiler optimisation when using

```
web3.eth.compile.solidity(...)
```

PS: using `solc-js` is not considered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like there's currently any way to change that setting.  In geth, it appears to be [enabled by default](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.5.9/common/compiler/solidity.go#L39), from [v1.2.1 onwards](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/17b729759b308a44ebe339fd373a190d0aaf1672#diff-fa62744b49ca57e70faa47010f117763R58).

Answer (score 0):

`web3` does not offer `compile.solidity()` method [anymore](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1000). You have to find out other method or stick with old libraries forever ;)